# How could i get a chars from a text file and put it into a 2D array?

Tags: java

for example:

```
-8-88-8-8-8--8

-8-8-8-8-8-8-8

*-8-8-8-8--8-8

8--8-8-8-8--8-
```

Comment: Does the example illustrate the input lines of the file or the desired 2D output array?

Comment: its just simple you need to follow the 2 steps from my answer

Answer (score 2):

1. Read text file line by line
2. Split string by `-` so you will have char array add it in your 2d char array.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use the [toCharArray()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method of String.

So if you are using a BufferedReader

```
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file"));
   while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
     list.add(thisLine);
   } 

   // finally convert the arraylist to a char[]
   char[] firstDimension = new char[list.size()];
   for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       firstDimension[i] = list.get(i).toCharArray();
   }
```

Comment: how would it be if im using a Scanner ??

Comment: bufferedreader is probably more suitable for this, but otherwise use scanner to read line by line

Answer (score 0):

char[] firsDimension is not 2d. Try something like,

```
    try {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        String thisLine = null;
        BufferedReader br;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file/yourfile.txt"));

        while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(thisLine);
        }

        char[][] firstDimension = new char[list.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            firstDimension[i] = list.get(i).toCharArray();
        }

        //print values
        for (int i=0;i<firstDimension.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<firstDimension[i].length;j++) {
                System.out.println(firstDimension[i][j]);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With scanner class

```
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(
                "/home/sinan/Desktop/yourfile.txt"));
        scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            list.add(scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();

        // finally convert the arraylist to a char[][]
        char[][] firstDimension = new char[list.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            firstDimension[i] = list.get(i).toCharArray();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < firstDimension.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < firstDimension[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(firstDimension[i][j]);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: how would it be if im using a Scanner ??

Comment: but if i want to print the double array  i want only what i wrote without the rest??